# Best Practice for saving many to one in order using NSSet?

Tags: swift, ios8, nsset

I am new to Swift and was wondering if anyone can give me some tips on how to store data in a Core Data NSSet sorted for an item that has the relationship one to many in order.  I have a book class (the many) and I have a shelf class (the one) that has an NSSet of books in it.

```
class Shelf: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var books: NSSet
}

class Book: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var title: String
}
```

I can add books to the shelf and that works, but the order seems to be random every time I try to access them instead of the order I added them.  I want the result in the order I added it to be retained.  Is there a way to do this without adding another class like bookOnShelf to store the position?

```
var booksInOrder = myShelf.books.AsAnyObject as [Book]
for(var i = 0; i < mySlelf.books.count; i++)
{
   output(booksInOrder[i])
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your CoreData model to enable the "Ordered" attribute of the relationship.

You'll also want to change the property declaration in your code to:

```
    @NSManaged var books: NSOrderedSet
```